# Interface Builder Autolayout and Resizing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, interface-builder

So I have two questions about Interface Builder for Xcode:

1. I'm trying to build an interface with a label on the left and a text field on the right, which have constant spacing between them, but I want the text field to expand horizontally when I resize the window horizontally to keep the spacing. I've added a restraint that keeps the spacing between them equal, but when I move the window, it resizes the label box rather than the text field. I tried pinning the width of the label, but then it stops me from resizing the window.
2. Is there any way to resize multiple items at the same time? Like if I have 8 labels vertically and I want to size them all to each be an 8th of the window space, how can I do that without just eyeballing it? It would be easy if you could highlight all of them and drag one corner to resize them all, but it wont let me do that.

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem you should **uncheck AutoLayout from Utilities Panel -> File Inspector** and see what happens. Concerning the second you can create how many labels you want with your desired size directly from code as follows :

Example for 10 labels:

```
for (int i=0; i<30; i++)

{

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:anyFrame];

[yourView addSubView:label];
[label release]; //if not using ARC


}
```

Comment: When I uncheck auotolayout it just gets rid of all the constraints, which isn't what I want to do, because then it doesn't resize anything if the window resizes.